# Was Sridhara Swami an Advaitan or a Vaishnava?

Tags: vaishnavism, sects

Sridhara Swami is generally referred to as an Advaita commentator but  this site https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-1-1/  says Sridhara Swami of Rudra sampradaya. Which is true?

Comment: @RaRe, the advaita in Bhagavatam is a philosophy of it's own. It is not nirvishesha advaita which accepts only the soul without personality. There is a book by Daniel Sheridan called 'The Advaitic theism of Bhagavata purana' which maybe of interest. It does explain the puzzle of what philosophy Bhagavatam propounds somewhat. The conclusion of the author is very similar to Chaitanya Mahaprabhu's conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sridhara Swami says in the introduction to his commentary of Srimad Bhagavad Gita the following:

> (1) I bow down to the wonderful Madhava (Sri Krishna), the embodiment
>   of supreme bliss, who with one mouth expressed what had been taught
>   with dexterity by Sesha through innumerable mouths.
>
> (2) After respectfully bowing down to Vishnu and Shiva, the Lord of
>   the universe, and being guided by devotion to them, I am writing this
>   commentary called Subodhini on the Gita.
>
> (3) **After scrutinizing according to my lights the views of the
>   commentator (Sankara), and likewise the words of his expounders, I am
>   beginning this commentary on the Gita.**
>
> (4) This gloss called Subodhini, a mere intelligent reading of which
>   elucidates the meaning of the Gita, should always be meditated upon by
>   the wise.

*Commentary by Sridhar Swami of Srimad Bhagavad Gita 1.1 translated by Swami Vireswarananda*

It  is clear that Sridhara Swami mentions that he read Sankara's commentary of the Gita to write his gloss. That would suggest that he was an Advaitist. There is a catch, however.

> ...yet his leaning towards devotion as opposed to knowledge is so very
>   marked that the orthodox section at first refused to accept his
>   commentary as authoritative. For a decision, the commentary was placed
>   before the Lord Visweswara (according to some, before the Lord
>   Bindumadhava) in Banaras, and tradition says that the Lord appeared in
>   a dream and gave the verdict thus;
>
> "I know the true teaching of the scriptures, and so does Suka. Vyasa
>   may or may not know. But Sridhara knows everything through the grace
>   of the Lord Nrisimha."
>
> After that the orthodox section withdrew their objections.

*Preface by Swami Vireswarananda to the English translation of Srimad Bhagavad Gita by Sridhara Swami*

I think it would be correct to say that Sridhara Swami was an Advaitist with leaning towards devotion. It would be a stretch to say anything more.